# How to Fix: "All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode! UnityEditor.SceneView:ShowCompileErrorNotification ()"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a problem with a compiler error in the Unity Engine that states: "All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!
UnityEditor.SceneView:ShowCompileErrorNotification ()"

I am following a Youtube video to create a Shooter Game and I am a Young Programmer Trying to Learn how to use the Unity Engine. I have Looked at both the code in the video and the code in my text editor and they appear exactly the same.

First Part of Code https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkzTh.png

Second Part of Code https://i.stack.imgur.com/etb7Z.png

The error in the Engine https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGlo8.png

Player Inputs https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnPMX.png

The scene in the engine https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9BiV.png

Any Help Would be Greatly Appriciated

Edit: It now shows in the console that there is a syntax error and an "identifier expected". Im not sure where to put the comma for the syntax error and Im not sure what identifier expected means

Errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFAE2.png
What it is highlighting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDJ9T.png

Comment: So... fix the compiler errors? Without any actual information we can't give you any more useful response

Comment: Check your "Console" tab. There are an errors in your code should be displayed there.

Comment: Dont show us the last errors, show us the first one. Clear it, show us the compile error, or more to the point, just fix the compile error (it will be right)

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes sorry I have just added screenshots of the situation. Im a bit new to this website and it deleted them before

Comment: @BugFinder will do right now

Comment: Okay I have fixed the syntax error

Comment: Do not post images of code! Code is text and should be included as such

Comment: Yes sorry I will copy and paste it in directly next time

Comment: I have fixed the syntax issue but im not at all sure what identifier expected means

Comment: If it's still the same error as before, then you wrote `Vector 2` instead of `Vector2`

Comment: Scroll to the top of the error list -- the first one is usually the most helpful/critical to fix. Sometimes it will clear up many that follow.

Comment: @UnholySheep already told you: you have a typo there. There is a space in `Vector 2` .. identifiers in c# can not start with numeric chars or be only a number => the very first error you get is `Identifier expected` ... everything else is just follow up hickups of the compiler trying to somewhat make sense of the rest of your code assuming the first issue was resolved

Comment: I have managed to append the errors, thankyou for your help. It was a matter of not properly understanding the syntax and not understanding the structure of the language